# Mac Mini 2013 remote setup with a macbook pro

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-control, server.app

I bought a current model mac mini server and it arrived today. Yay.

I have a macbook pro running 10.8 and the server is connected to my router by ethernet, laptop is connected wirelessly to same router.

The mac mini is straight out of the box, yet to have it's OS set up. Yes I turned it on.

I have assigned the mac mini an ip address of 192.168.1.222 which I can verify is accessible through the terminal with $ ping 192.168.1.222 returning the expected response.

However, when I go through Finder->CMD-K I get connection failed.

My network preferences screen sharing set to on.

Thoughts?

Comment: Ping does not show the required access, ping is inert command, you can ping anyone. So check the following: Accessing servers on your network that use Apple Filing Protocol (AFP) over TCP/IP, including OS X Servers.

Comment: No I realise ping doesn't prove access, but it does prove that the server exists on the network. I googled the text you gave me but couldn't find anything usedful. What did you mean by it?

Comment: It might also be worth noting that if I attempt to telnet or ssh to the server I get a connection refused failure

Comment: Actually, it is not clear to me if you have completed the set up on both sides?

Comment: The Mac Mini is not set up at all. Straight out of the box plugged in and turned on. (I don't have a screen). The laptop is set up (Had it since 2010)

Answer (score 2):

I'm in the process to buy a Mac Mini and want to setup without keyboard and screen and found this:

> Using Screen Sharing or Apple Remote Desktop
>
> If the remote server is running Lion Server v10.7.2 or later, you can
>   set it up using Screen Sharing or Apple Remote Desktop.
>
> On your administrator computer, look for the remote server in the
>   Shared computer list of the Finder sidebar, or in the Scanner list in
>   Remote Desktop. The new server may be listed with a name generated
>   from the computer model and the Ethernet hardware address (the MAC
>   address), or with a name from your DNS server. If the server you want
>   to set up is listed in the Finder sidebar, double click it, then click
>   Share Screen... in the upper-right corner of the Finder window. If the
>   server you want to set up is listed in the Remote Desktop Scanner,
>   select it, then click the Control icon in the Remote Desktop toolbar.
>   When prompted for authentication, leave the user name blank and enter
>   the remote server’s complete hardware serial number for the password.
>   You can find the serial number on the case of the product, on the
>   original product packaging, and on the original product receipt or
>   invoice. For more information about finding the serial number, see How
>   to find the serial number of your Apple hardware product.
>
> Note: Match the capitalization of the serial number when you type it.
>   When you have control of the remote server's screen, proceed through
>   the server setup assistant panes.

[Lion Server: Setting up a remote server](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4938)

Comment: This is entirely correct. It works.

Comment: This only works for the (old) Mac Mini **Server** models as I am currently learning and therefore no longer works with current line-up of Mac Mini models, which may also be due to Apple's move to the Mac App Store approach of installing the (newish) Server.app